# Angular 2: Expression has changed after it was checked on accessing child component property

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two tab components that I pass the same model data but filtered with a custom pipe:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="All ({{ allPeople.count }})">
        <tab-content #allPeople [content]="data"></tab-content>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Tennagers ({{ teenagers.count }})">
        <tab-content #teenagers [content]="data | filterByAge: 20"></tab-content>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

On the parent component, I want to access a property of a child. As you see I am doing that with ID connection: `{{ allPeople.count }}`

On the child component, I have `ngOnChanges()` method that do some calculations and return the `count` property:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.count = this.countPeople();
}
```

With this approach, it works but the following console error appears:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'All
>   (0)'. Current value: 'All (4)'.

I know that it appears only in the development mode, but I also know that it is not a good practice. Is there another way that I can access the child property `count` when I have same changes on with.

Here is a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/YlKxh81ejJF7zofc4310?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when change detection causes changes to the mode. Because `ngOnChanges()` is called by change detection, this is probably what causes the error in your case. You can work around be calling change detection explicitely after the update.

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnChanges() {
    setTimeout(() => this.count = this.countPeople());
    // this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

I don't know why `detectChanges()` didn't work in your case, but `setTimeout()` did. I assume it's related to other components depending on the change. `detectChanges` works only on the current component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) is this solution a good practice and is there a better way how to do it? Maybe there is a reason why this error appears :)

Comment: I haven't seen anything better yet. Try to avoid changing the model in `ngOnChanges`, but usually there is no good alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix the error. This is updated plunker with  your solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/YlKxh81ejJF7zofc4310?p=preview

Comment: Your Plunker looks weird. Didn't you use a template from Plunker or from Angular GitHub issues?

Comment: Just use the "new" button in Plunker and you get a nice template.

Comment: Tried a few things, none worked https://plnkr.co/edit/2qThXqdWzvnxhG3puFcw?p=preview. Sorry out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you! I have some ideas and later I will create the new plunker. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Uh, forgot the last method which worked (setTimeout) https://plnkr.co/edit/ul21TgIcdQc2Ql8CAg7d?p=preview

Comment: Your solution works good, thank you :) I moved your ```this.cdRef.detectChanges();``` to ```ngAfterContentChecked``` method of the parent component and also works good. Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Fj6byAyAC5rbk7LovibU?p=preview